# Как можно в Telethon можно обойти ввод номера телефона и кода из тг в консоли (доступ к аккаунту есть)

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

Мне надо обойти вот эти запросы в консоле (чтобы они сами автоматом заполнялись, либо полностью избавиться от этого если это возможно) (доступ к аккаунту у меня есть к которому я пытаюсь подключиться)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мой код:

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
from telethon.tl import functions, types
import time

api_id = '7'
api_hash = '7'


client = TelegramClient('my_session', api_id, api_hash)

input_message = ('blablabla')


async def send_message_to_channel(channel_username, message_text):
    try:
        entity = await client.get_entity(channel_username)

        await client.send_message(entity, message_text)

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Произошла ошибка: {e}")


async def main():
    await client.start()

    channel_messages = {
        'https://t.me/canal': f'{input_message}',
        'https://t.me/canal': f'{input_message}',
        'https://t.me/canal': f'{input_message}',
    }

    while True:
        for channel_username, message_text in channel_messages.items():
            await send_message_to_channel(channel_username, message_text)

        time.sleep(5)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import asyncio

    asyncio.run(main())
```